# Redirection to custom 404 error page

Tags: html, .htaccess

I was not able to find a straight answer for my question. I have 2 other websites (eg website 'A' and website 'B') under my current website (www.xyz.com). Both the website is in different folder. So to access my sub website url will be www.xyz.com/A/ or www.xyz.com/B/. I have created a 404.html page for my main website (www.xyz.com). How can I use the same 404.html page for my sub websites. I tried `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`

It is working for my main website, but not working for my sub websites kindly advice.

Comment: Did you try to create a custom .htaccess file in each subfolder with a relative path to the error document like ../404.html?

Comment: You have to point to the document. Right now your `.htaccess` is pointing to a `/404.html` that it thinks is in the **`/B/`** directory.

Comment: You can use `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` from root .htaccess of main website but you need to have `404.html` present in each website's root path. (You can create symlinks of the main `404.html`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citation from [How to redirect your 404](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/)

*htaccess 404 Error Code
Once you have your 404 page setup, all you need to do is send visitors of incorrect url’s to this page. To do this just add the following line to your .htaccess file :
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php*

*Most often, the .htaccess file will be in the* **home root public_html** *folder on your server. This can change, for an example if you run you site or blog out of a specific folder within the public_html.*

*Alternately, You can place the 404 error template anywhere you want in a folder. For example you could place all error messages in a folder called errormessages refererring the 404 error to the url of the page.
ErrorDocument 404 /errormessages/404.php*

*That’s all there is to it.
Now when a visitor views an incorrect url on your site they will see your custom 404 error message.*

**when do you have a web.xml** with this pattern you can set an errorpage too:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/Error404.html</location>
</error-page>
```